# When is Co-variance multiplication of Standard Deviations?

Tags: probability, covariance

So I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieL0jxzLhCE&t=4s) on which states Co-Varince of $X$ and $Y$ as:
$$cov(X,Y) = \sigma_X \sigma_Y$$
I have not come across this formulae anywhere before. The closest is when we define:
$$ \rho = \frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}$$ and if $\rho = 1$ then the former formulae holds true. What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That formula doesn't hold true. It is just horrible "notation" or a "writeo" or whatever. The formula shown for covariance in terms of summation is correct. Apparently covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is denoted $\sigma_X \sigma_Y$ in the video, but that is just terrible, because it looks like the standard deviations of $X$ and $Y$ are being multiplied, which is not the case. However, $\sigma_{X,Y}$ is often uised to denote the covariance of $X$ and $Y$.

Also, he said the variance is larger than the standard deviation, which is not true when the standard deviation is less than 1.

My advice: Don't use these videos.